# Edit some preferences in Eclipse using Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to edit the following preferences using the java code

1. Eclipse-Preferences-General-Workspace-Text file encoding-Others-UTF-8
2. Run dialog-Run configurations-Common tab-encoding-Others-UTF-8
3. Run dialog-Run configurations-Arguments tab-write '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' in the 'VM Arguments' text box
4. Add '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' in 'eclipse.ini' file in the Eclipse folder

I need to have a method that adjusts the 4 things when it's called so I want to adjust the preferences above using java not manualyy .. how can I do that ?

Comment: I want to adjust the preferences above using java not manualyy .. how can I do that ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Which scenario makes this necessary? Preferences are [exportable](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/timpandexp.htm) ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn how to do [Eclipse Plugin Development](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html) and then getting at the various property pages and manipulating them will require you to get familiar with the Eclipse RCP, and you will need to know how to query the workspace etc.  Look at the book [Eclipse Plug-ins](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321553462)